# Grep in R (zero or any character)

Tags: r, dataframe, xls

I have files with a lot of data, but in several of them date is in this format:
YYYYMMDD, f. e. 20150704

And in the others date is in this format:
YYYY-MM-DD, f. e. 2015-07-04

I want to grep to find specific date, can I do this by one grep to both examples?

I tried this:

```
grep("*07*04",file)
```

and this

```
grep(".07.04",file)
```

Second form worked for this format YYYY-MM-DD but not for YYYYMMDD

Is there any way to do this by one grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
grep('-?07-?04$', str1)
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c('2015-07-04', '20150704', '2014-08-07', '20150407',
          '2015-07-14', '2015-01-04')
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems fairly simple:

```
grep('07-*04',str1)
```

The asterisk quantifier says "zero or more times" for the character or group immediately to its left. And fortunately dash is not a special regex symbol. If it were you would either need to use square-brackets to make a character class or doubly escape. (I got the idea that you thought the asterisk was a wildcard and that's not the case.)

Comment: Although at the moment this would find dates like "2007-04-01", not just "XXXX-07-04", which doesn't seem to be the aim (although it's not clear in the question)

Comment: If you wanted to make it more specific then use "\\d{4}-*07-*04"

Comment: @ping Based on your example, the solution using `gsub` will also fail

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `gsub` first:

```
str1 <- c('2015-07-04', '20150704', '2014-08-07', '20150407',
       '2015-07-14', '2015-01-04')

grep('*0704',gsub("-","",str1))
```

Comment: as mentioned by @akrun this will match dates like "2007-04-01", which doesn't seem like what OP means by "specific date"; although I like the idea of using gsub to convert all dates to the same format.

Comment: Agree, best to clean up data first; into date format or POSIX